# Showing/Decoding received chat message XMPP framework ios

Tags: iphone, ios, chat, xmppframework

I am able to send Message to specific Person selected through XMPPframework IOS. I am receiving messages from others sent to me and I can see using NSLog in following method.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

I have gone through What I want to know is, if any method available in XMPP to directly decode received chat message ? i.e. like If

```
- [message getChatMessage];
```

Or we need to implement on our own ? i.e decoding received XML and get requirement element string.

Please share if any one knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get, for example, the body of the message by doing this:

```
NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
```

The values for other tags can be found like this.  XMPP uses XML to structure its data, so the elementForName: and attributeForName: methods should give you the data you need.

Comment: Thax a lost. Saved my time. Worked like a charm.